# How to destroy Charts in chartJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, chart.js

I have an angular +  Ionic app in which I am using chartJS to show some data. Now charts are implemented on a slider.
[Link1](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/29)  [Link2](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/59) and there are similar linked issues.
The solution that I came across. from many of the post is that I would have to destroy the existing chart and recreate in my window. Because whenever I change options via a drop drow the view blows up, all slides instead of coming next to each other laterally, Start showing up vertically and when I change the device mode. It actually re renders the page  and I can view it normally.

I have tried it using ng-if also but it doesn't work.  **So how do I destroy a chart in my angular App and then recreate it**

Some HTML code as to how am I doing it.

```
<div ng-if="metricArray">
        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" style="height:50%">
            <ion-slide ng-repeat="metric in metricArray">
                <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px; color:#eee;">
                    {{metric.startDate}} &nbsp;&nbsp;{{metric.endDate}}
                </div>
                <canvas id="myCanvas" tc-chartjs-bar chart-options="options" chart-data="metric.data" auto-legend></canvas>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top:30px;">
                    <div style="width:33%; text-align:center">
                        <h6 style="color:#eee">MAX</h6>
                        <div class="circleBase type1 " style="padding:15px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                            <h6 style="color:#eee">{{metric.max}}</h6>
                            <p style="color:#eee">{{metricUnit}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:33%; text-align:center">
                        <h6 style="color:#eee">MIN</h6>
                        <div class="circleBase type1 " style="padding:15px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                            <h6 style="color:#eee">{{metric.min}}</h6>
                            <p style="color:#eee">{{metricUnit}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:33%; text-align:center">
                        <h6 style="color:#eee">AVG</h6>
                        <div class="circleBase type1 " style="padding:15px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                            <h6 style="color:#eee">{{metric.avg}}</h6>
                            <p style="color:#eee">{{metricUnit}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you try to remove data using mychart.removeData();

Comment: I have made an edit. I don't have a variable called myChart in my html. and is removeData a standard function ?

Comment: myChart is just a name of canvas and yes , removeData is standard function . you can  check in official doc of Chart.js

Comment: I am not using chartjs directly  I am using [Angular directive for ChartJS](http://carlcraig.github.io/tc-angular-chartjs/)  and myChart is not the name of canvas. This is how it is declared `var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);` and used `myLineChart.removeData();` like this and calling removeData() on your Chart instance will remove the first value for all datasets on the chart.